# EditText value is getting replaced with another edit text on backpress

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am in a situation here, I've two edit text in a fragment, on back press the value of first edit text is getting replaced by second edit text. Now both the edit text are having same values.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="hint" />
```

Above is my `EditText`, this EditText is inside a layout and I've included the layout in my fragment two times to get the `EditText`, on click of submit I replace this fragment with another one but on backpress when I come back to this fragment, the value of first edit box is getting replaced by second one. Now both has same values.

This is how I am replacing fragment.

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.layout_fragment, fragment, tag);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

Comment: i think you are using only one edit text?i am correct?

Comment: no I am not, I am using two edit text, this edit text is inside some layout and I am including that layout two times in my fragment's layout.

Comment: Use different id when including the Editext layout.

Comment: check both  android:id="@+id/edit_text" are different

Comment: I have tried adding the text layout on runtime also using custom view, that also isn't working. If I am adding 2 edit text on runtime using same id won't effect.

Answer (score 1):

You should use different id for the EditText.

Assume the EditText is defined in `edit_text_layout.xml`, when including the layout, specify different id.

In `fragment_layout.xml`:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/edit_text_layout"
    android:id="@+id/edit_text_1" />

<include
    layout="@layout/edit_text_layout"
    android:id="@+id/edit_text_2" />
```

Explain:
Android save a view's state in a SparseArray, the key is the view's id. When restoring the state, views have the same id will be get the same state value.
If the view doesn't have an id (`NO_ID`), its state won't be saved or restored.

`android.view.View.java`

```
protected void dispatchSaveInstanceState(SparseArray<Parcelable> container) {
    if (mID != NO_ID && (mViewFlags & SAVE_DISABLED_MASK) == 0) {
        ......
        if (state != null) {
            ......
            container.put(mID, state);
        }
    }
}

protected void dispatchRestoreInstanceState(SparseArray<Parcelable> container) {
    if (mID != NO_ID) {
        Parcelable state = container.get(mID);
        if (state != null) {
            ......
            onRestoreInstanceState(state);
            ......
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think same `id` is an issue here. When I set the initial values for both the edit texts, it correctly identifies them and saves the values in 2 different edit texts but in backpress the first edit text value is getting replaced by second edit text and value in second edit text remains intact.

Comment: Please change the ids and try it.

Comment: If changing the id is only solution then how does custom view works when you have to add multiple views based on the data coming from list or wherever and in that case all is having same ids?

One more addition - If I put TextView instead of Edit Text value remains intact on back press as well.

Comment: @DisplayName It is the ```id```'s problem.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your EditTexts are using the same id.  In your XML files you need to make sure that the id for both edit texts are different. Even if there are in separate XML files, they must have different ids.

For instance, you might change their declarations to...

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/edit_text1"

<EditText
android:id="@+id/edit_text2"
```

Comment: Then in that case it should fail while the fragment is loaded, why it is failing in case of back press, When I set the text values when the fragment is loaded it sets the value in different different edit texts. Why values getting replaced in backpress?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I ran into a very similar issue and although the current answers are correct (its a duplicate ID issue), the actual answers given weren't working or quite in the right area.

I had a Fragment, and in that Fragment I had 2 custom controls, both with unique ID's, but internally in those controls they included the same common Layout, and so that Layout of course had an EditText with the same ID in both.

@wrkwrk is right in that its an ID issue, but changing the ID on the "include" isn't enough if the included layout contains the EditText, and if you want to include the same layout multiple times, you can't give it a different ID in the axml.

So for my work around, in the code for my custom control that loads the EditText in, after loading it in I simply changed the ID afterwards using the View.GenerateViewId() function.

So something like (this is in C#/Xamarin)

```
        var editText = _root.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.entryEditText);
        editText.Id = GenerateViewId();
```

That seemed to fix the issues for me. So I can have one common ID in the layout so my control can find it fine, but then it changes so multiple instances of that control in a fragment will all save off their EditText state fine when going back.

Alternatively, you could give it no ID in the layout but a Tag instead and do FindViewByTag and then assign it an ID after loading.

Comment: This can happen when you have multiple fragment in activity and you used add fragment concept additionally your fragment should have multiple custom edit text then this scenario can reproduce!